# jquery doesn't get PHP variable value from DIV data-id, just outputs variable name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have:

```
<div class= "obutton feature2" data-id=".$bookID."><button>Reserve Book</button></div> 
<div class="modal-box"></div>
```

This is the button that calls the jquery, however the modal box it makes just outputs ".$bookID." and not the actually value within.

The jquery script is:

```
<script>
    $('button').click(function() 
    {
        var book_id = $(this).parent().data('id'),
        result = "Book #" + book_id + " has been reserved.";

        $('.modal-box').text(result).fadeIn(700, function() 
        {
            setTimeout(function() 
            {
        $('.modal-box').fadeOut();
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

All help appreciated -Tom

Comment: your jq script worked [demo](http://jsbin.com/uyUBIta/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's php then it should be within tags:

```
<div class= "obutton feature2" data-id="<?php echo $bookID; ?>">
  <button>Reserve Book</button>
</div>
```

Or if the whole thing is a printed string then you must escape your quotes or use single quotes:

```
<?php
  echo '<div class= "obutton feature2" data-id="' . $bookID . '">
     <button>Reserve Book</button>
  </div>'; 
?>
```

Comment: I just realised this as you answered, just dawned upon me that it wasn't inside php tags, thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Tom No problem. Don't forget to mark this question as answered.